# `columns` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(DataGrid)`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I am having a weird issue with MUI datagrid. Below is the code

```
const mcolumns=[
    { field: "firstname", headerName: "Firstname" },
    { field: "lastname", headerName: "Lastname"}
]

const pastors = [
    {firstname:"Sherebiah", lastname:"Tisbi"}
]

const Pastorlist = () => {
    return (
        <Box mt={2}>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item>
                    controls
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    {pastors.length>0
                        ? <DataGrid>
                            rows={pastors}
                            columns={mcolumns}
                            pageSize={5}
                        </DataGrid>
                        : <Typography variant="h6" >No pastor for this church yet!</Typography>
                    }
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

I am getting errors

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `columns` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(DataGrid)`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

and also

```
react_devtools_backend.js:3973 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `rows` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(DataGrid)`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

I am not sure what is wrong in here. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have Wasted on a Whole day for this issue,
Just put

```
getRowId={(rows) => rows._id}
```

this line in datagrid area, automatically it will take data from backend.

This reference only for react and express and mongodb users...

```
<DataGrid columns={columns} rows={products} getRowId={(rows) => rows._id} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so finally I found the issue. I was passing all props as a children element of DataGrid!!! :) This kind of silly mistakes costs days.!